# Is "es" necessary in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

I wanted to say "I forgot what I wanted to google". But I'm not sure whether I should say...

a-) Ich habe vergessen, was ich googeln wollte.

or

b-) Ich habe **es** vergessen, was ich googeln wollte.

The "was" in the sentence makes me unsure, as I think, it introduces a Nebensatz. Is the "Es" really necessary? Why?

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: No, es isn't necessary in _"Ich habe vergessen, was ich googeln wollte."_.

Comment: next to *bestimmt* / *unbestimmt*, this is among the most difficult areas of everyday speech grammar for learners of German to master. I know many advanced learners who achieve almost native fluency, but keep getting *this* wrong. good question.

Comment: No worries, really. *Hochdeutsch* is a synthetic language and such tiny glitches may be common in at least *one* dialect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's neither neccessary nor preferred.

Your example is tricky as **was** (and other question words, too!) can both introduce an object clause and a relative clause:

> Ich sehe, was du nicht siehst.

This *was du nicht siehst* is clearly an object clause. It is used as the accusative object of *sehen*.

> Ich sehe was, was du nicht siehst.

Here, the first *was* is the accusative object to *sehen*, and the following clause is merily an explanation to the *was*. It's a relative clause.

---

Your example works the same:

> Ich habe vergessen, was ich googeln wollte.

Here, *was ich googlen wollte* is an object clause.

> Ich habe **das** vergessen, was ich googeln wollte.

Here, *was ich googlen wollte* is a relative clause referring to the demonstrative pronoun *das*. In sloppy speech, one may use *es* instead of *das* and make it a very weak accusative object. The meaning is the same.

Comment: In my opinion only Ich habe vergessen, was ich googlen wollte sounds natural to me. The rest sounds kinda clumsy although it might be grammatically correct.

Comment: *Ich sehe was, was du nicht siehst.* is the literal name of a children's game. So this pattern is obviously also common.

Comment: Muss im ersten Beispiel das Komma stehen?

Comment: Es handelt sich bei dem Teil nach dem Komma um einen Objektsatz, daher ja.